# "Transparent" border around items on background

Tags: css, transparency

There have been several questions regarding some kind of transparent border but not what I am looking for, I think.

[image]

It might be very stupid but: Is it possible somehow to have items (*those white squares*) on a background (*the black texture*) with  those items each having a border that "remove" the background for a 10px (or whatever) border?
So you have a continuous background and each item on top of it "cuts out" some part of it.
A true "transparent" border (like other questions) obviously would just let you see the background, so that is not what I mean.

If not, what would be the way to achieve a responsive design like that?

Sorry, I don't know any other way to explain it. Thank you.

See example/fiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/14nn2pLy](https://jsfiddle.net/14nn2pLy)

```css
   html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fd1dfa;
}

#main_header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: url() no-repeat center top;
    background-size: contain;
}

#main_footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/hACMzS/background_footer.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: contain;
}

#icons {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 75px;
    background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/mkPODn/footer_items.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    border: 10px;
    border-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="main_header"></div>

<div id="main_footer">
    <div id="icons"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any code that can show your issue and eventually your failed attempts ?  maybe there is a css method or maybe not , codes, image and browsers targeted matter ;) Can you clarify the question

Comment: Presuming each of those squares are divs you can give them a 4px border width and set the border color to rgba( 0,0,0,0) The last 0 is setting the opacity to 0.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen i understand that the black parts are to be blend / fade into the fuschia .... blend mode could do , not opacity ;)  OP's code is missing to eventually have a real clue

Comment: @MrLister yes sounds good too for 2 borders as long as the white stripes are spared ;)

Comment: See example/fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/14nn2pLy/

Ya, border color to transparent, makes the border transparent. Then you have no border because you see the background. Goal is to "remove" the background for the place around the items...

Comment: I think you can achieve it repeating the background and using an SVG mask. In place of a tutorial I link you this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/) which, in my opinion, goes right to the point.

Comment: Oh nice, that might be it. Thank you. Will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My thought process

The only way I can think of is to make the border the same color as the background (in your case, that shade of pink), but note that this is only possible if there is a solid background color.

Example:

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/nRXO8xa.jpg);
}

.border {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: steelblue;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.no-border {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: steelblue;
  border: 10px solid #F7F2D5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="border">black border</div>
  <div class="no-border">"transparent" border</div>
</div>
```

---

### **Solution:**

The desired effect is possible using `clip-path` on the background. Notice that I've changed the HTML and CSS too, otherwise it wouldn't work. The `clip-path` is used to basically *cut out* the part of the background image you don't want, so that it becomes *transparent*, and it is activated on hover.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473662712020-75289ee3c5de);
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  height: 140px;
  width: 618px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg {
  height: 140px;
  width: 618px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.25%;
  left: 38.25%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.icon:hover+.bg {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 44% 78.5%, 37.5% 50%, 44% 22%, 50.5% 50%, 44% 78.5%, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V2eI4Rm.png" alt="icon">
  </div>

  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D3V3ZYq.png" alt="background">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but yeah there is/should be no solid background. So as I assumed there is no way probably. But how is it done then in different designs and whatnot? I saw it often that an item has a "border" to stand out from a background. Hmm.

Comment: You can edit the pictures in photoshop how you want them to be, but I can't think of a way to do that through CSS. Do you have a better example that I can look at?

Comment: Yeah, I can make the icons partly transparent. Doesn't solve what I want to achieve though because as soon as there is something transparent, the background shines through obviously.

Hmm, it's more of a general question not to a specific example. But yeah, have an icon over a background, but to let the icon "stand out", have the background be "removed" around that item. Don't know how else I can explain, but you know what I mean, do you?

If not CSS, what would be a way then? Thanks.

Comment: "have the background be removed around that item", what would that look like? Because all I can think of is a solid color border around that icon that makes it look like the background is gone. If you're talking about the content around the icon, you can always increase the margin. Could you maybe give me a background (image) and an icon that you would like to see it work on, so I can play around with it?

Comment: I assume it's not possible, just was wondering how this kind of design is made in other cases. Here would be the images: First two original transparent pngs. last two jpgs as examples how it should be like.
https://image.ibb.co/iFYoM7/bg.png
https://image.ibb.co/mxpjuS/icon.png
https://image.ibb.co/emFPuS/icon_on_bg_border.jpg
https://image.ibb.co/bLQPuS/icon_on_bg_noborder.jpg

Comment: Thanks, this will help greatly. I'll do this first thing in the morning!

Comment: Just making sure I understand you correctly, this is what you want, correct? But then to be able to use a non-solid background, like an image, so that the same effect is visible? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL413jrx/)

Comment: Exactly, in the background there is whatever, so it has to shine through the transparent places in the element background and that border around the icon.. Thanks so much.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? If so, I will make it an answer so you can accept it as the official answer. Otherwise I am happy to help you further. I like the challenge :)

Comment: Well, the example was as I wanted on first glance, but as you said, it should be possible to "use a non-solid background, like an image, so that the same effect is visible". But I don't think it's possible, so...

Comment: Not so fast! I've managed to create the effect with clip-path. The desired effect is incredibly tedious to produce, especially if you want more than 1 of these icons, but **it is possible**. I've updated my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer, I put a lot of effort into it :)

Comment: You're welcome. That was my most interesting challenge so far, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could create a image with transparent background and use that as a border-image.

```css
.background {
position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fd1dfa;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.background:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

hr {
  border: 10px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 5 !important;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fd1dfa;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.border {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8 !important;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  background: white;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
 <hr>
  <div class="border">
    <div class="center">
      text and words
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border">
    <div class="center">
      text and words
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border">
    <div class="center">
      text and words
    </div>
  </div>
   
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but no, since there is the "background-color" on the border - which doesn't make it "transparent"

Comment: @Grimwood, okay. maybe something with canvas or svg. latest edit is as close as i can get