# Clip-path image - need transparent border on image

Tags: css, image, sass, border

I have an image in the shape of a hexagon that I'd like to apply a 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .141) border onto. The border needs to be on the image and not outside of it. Here is the code I have for the shape.

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 67px;
    top: 25px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  }
```

Any support for the best way to go at this would be great!

Comment: You need to border to follow the shape ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I need the 'border' to go on top of the image. It will be mostly transparent so you can see through it and see the image underneath it. I feel like I need two layers on the image - like a layer to add a transparency then a layer that is 4px bigger each direction to cut the hexagon. I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Comment: you need inded extra layers, but you should do this via SVG, not CSS ;)

Comment: OsuDani, my answer on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122150/transparent-border-around-items-on-background/50122499#50122499) question might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at mix-blend-mode *(using pseudos to create the blend-mode effect)* if your browser supports it:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width: 67px;
  
}

div::before,
div::after,
div img {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
    top:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0%,
    100% 25%,
    100% 75%,
    50% 100%,
    0% 75%,
    0% 25%
  );
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
div::before,
div::after {
  z-index:1;
  content:"";
  background:rgba(0,0,0, .141) ;
  
}
div::before {
  height:61px;
  width:54px;
  top:7px;
  left:7px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  mix-blend-mode:overlay;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/thumbs/3249/3249390-freestyle-man.jpg">
</div>
  original image
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/thumbs/3249/3249390-freestyle-man.jpg">
```

In my opinion, this is an SVG job ;)

Comment: Thanks! This is really close to what I need but I think its causing some color variance to the part of the image I don't want to change. I'll definitely look into SVG as an option. If you know any good svg generators, let me know :)